# EntityFramework 6 hangs forever on concurrent Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to do some profiling against the NorthWind Database to test performance issues.

How ever my query runs and hangs for ever.  What is weird is that everything works fine when we have say 4 CONCURRENT_CALLS

I'm running EF6 with SQL Server 2016

I'm aware entityframework doesn't work well with async request on the same context, so we spawn a new context each thread.

```
class Program
{
    public static int MAX_IO_THREADS = 2000;
    public static int MIN_IO_THREADS = 1000;
    public static int CONCURRENT_CALLS = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureThreadPool();
        WarmUpContexts();

        ProfileAction();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    protected static void ProfileAction()
    {
        var callRange = Enumerable.Range(0, CONCURRENT_CALLS);

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

        Parallel.ForEach(callRange, i =>
        {
            var callSw = new Stopwatch();
            callSw.Start();
            var result = RunTest().Result;
            callSw.Stop();

            results.TryAdd(i, $"Call Index: {i} took {callSw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds to complete");

        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var milliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        foreach (var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total Time " + milliseconds);
    }

    public static void ConfigureThreadPool()
    {
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out var defaultMinWorkerCount, out var _);
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var defaultMaxWorkerCount, out var _);

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(defaultMaxWorkerCount, MAX_IO_THREADS);
        var successMin = ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(defaultMinWorkerCount, MIN_IO_THREADS);
    }

    static void WarmUpContexts()
    {
        using (var stagingContext = new NORTHWNDEntities())
        {
            stagingContext.Employees.First();
        }
    }


    static async Task<int> RunTest()
    {
        using (var context = new NORTHWNDEntities())
        {
            var employees = await context.Employees.ToArrayAsync();
            return employees.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried modify the gcServer to work better with concurrency

```
<runtime>
  <gcServer enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

And I've modified my connection string to increase Min Pool size

> integrated security=True; pooling = true; Min Pool Size = 100;

Everything hangs forever. 
When I run sp_whoisactive on sql, I can see that there is (636ms)ASYNC_NETWORK_IO on my user is trapped,  and there is only one connection which displays at a time.

Is this a bug in entityframework?

Comment: Are you meaning to use `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()` for both defaultMin and defaultMax?

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Do you get any output? i.e "Call Index: blah" statements?

Comment: No it never returns, I can see in SQL it's trying to send everything back. but for some reason my thread execution never gets the response back

Comment: is sp_whoisactive showing any deadlocks ?

Comment: It’s looks like sql has complete and it’s waiting for .net to read the network

Comment: No deadlocks, Im only reading data on an isolated network with no writes to the db

Comment: what does your connection string look like? I'd specify `pooling=true;Min Pool Size={CONCURRENT_CALLS}` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for that tip I’ll check it out when I get into work

Comment: @zaitsman that didn't fix the issue but it gives me more to play with thank you